# How to restrict an iframe to a specific domain

Tags: html, security, iframe

I know I can check the request headers for the referrer. Is that enough? For example – How does a service like Disqus securely prevent another site from embedding someone else's comment thread?

Comment: Disqus sends an awful lot of requests to their services, so I think there is some intricate javascript authentication used.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out what I was looking is the `X-Frame-Options response header`. It lets you specify the origin an iframe can be rendered in.

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

Comment: 'ALLOW-FROM uri' has very limited support on browsers

Answer (score 2):

The [`X-Frame-Options`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) header only really allows for blanket `DENY` and `SAMEORIGIN` settings, and has been made obsolete by the newer [`Content-Security-Policy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy) headers.

CSP [`frame-ancestors`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors) can be used in all modern browsers to restrict iframe embeds to certain domains. E.g.:

```
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' https://www.example.org;
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into browser headers (they are a very powerful and relatively new security mechanism), however I believe that different browsers have variations in how the implement headers (for a change :-(  )

Comment: This is a very vague answer - *which* headers?